# Context menu not working in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, flex4.6

Context menu is not working with datagrid in flex 4.6 sdk. I have a project developed using flex 3.6 sdk. My goal was to make it compatible to run in flex 4.6 sdk .Its running fine in flex 4.6 but the context menu is not working. Any idea how to implement the context menu in a datagrid in flex 4.6 .

Answer (score 1):

It worked . If we assign the context menu using the id of datagrid then the context menu works, for example if the id of datagrid is dg, then by using dg.contextmenu = cm. But I wonder why it doesn't work by assigning it directly in datagrid using binding.